# When Resources of a PE file are loaded

Tags: windows, visual-c++, embedded-resource, portable-executable

When using a resource included in a PE file (for example a binary resource) in C++ . we have to 
first call

1 )FindResource and then

2 )LoadResource

to access the resource .

Being accurate about the function name "LoadResource"  i wonder if the "Windows Loader" does load all resource of an application in memory just when loading other parts (like code or data section)  or they are delay loaded only when we need them ?

If so can we unload these resources after we have used them in order to free allocated memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These functions are old, they date back to Windows versions that did not yet support virtual memory.  Back in the olden days they would actually physically load a resource into RAM.

Those days are long gone, the OS loader creates a memory-mapped file to map the executable file into memory.  And anything from the file (code and resources) are only mapped into RAM when the program dereferences a pointer.  You only pay for what you use.

So LoadResource() does very little, it simply returns a pointer, disguised as a HGLOBAL handle.  LockResource() does nothing interesting, it simply casts the HGLOBAL back to a pointer.  When you actually start using it then you'll trip a page fault and the kernel reads the file, loading it into RAM.  UnlockResource() and FreeResource() do nothing.  If the OS needs RAM for another process then it can unmap the RAM for the resource.  Nothing needs to be preserved since the memory is backed by the file, the page can simply be discarded.  Paged back in when necessary if you use the resource again.