# PE Loading: What to do with resource section?

Tags: windows, winapi, portable-executable

I'm studying PE file format and how windows loads them. I already know about most sections and how they get loaded/mapped in memory. But I have no idea what happens to resource section since all addresses in there seem to be sequential and doesn't seem to need any change.

I've made a test loader that does the basic loading but the target .exe file has resources in it and they never get loaded.

Comment: Doesn't it happen on demand when the program attempts to load resources?

Comment: not need any special processing. @DavidHeffernan - no, resourse mapped to memory when pe loaded. `LoadResource` not actually load any data, but return address in memory where resource already mapped.

Comment: @RbMm That's a yes then, the virtual memory system loads the data on page fault when first accessed

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It might not need any manual mapping **if** the PE is loaded at default address (0x00400000). But since the PE could load at any virtual address manually, `LoadIcon` and friends won't ever find the resource at expected location.

Comment: What you are talking about there is not mapping. You are talking about relocations. Resources don't need relocations. You need to read up on what mapping is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hmm, then I assume resource section needs no modification when it's being loaded, right? Since the address of each directory or node is relative to first resource directory.

Comment: The directory is relative to the base address, and the resource API functions account for that

Comment: So the directory and entry's offsets must be set according to the new base address right?

Answer (score 2):

According to [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format)

> It is important to recognize that PE files are not loaded into memory as single memory mapping files.Windows loader (also known as PE loader) traverses PE files and decides which part of the file is mapped. This mapping method maps the higher offset of the file to the higher memory address. PE file structure is basically the same in disk and memory, but it is not completely copied when loaded into memory. The Windows loader decides which parts to load and which parts do not need to be loaded. Moreover, due to the inconsistency between disk alignment and memory alignment, the distribution of PE files loaded into memory will be different from that of PE files on disk.

Here is a picture :application loaded into memory

[Memory mapping picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alU9A.png)

The base address value is set by PE file itself. According to the default settings, the EXE file established by visual c++ has the base address of 00400000h and the base address of DLL file is 10000000h. However, you can change this address when creating an application by using the connector / BASE option when connecting to the application, or by setting it up through the REBASE application after linking.

In addition,  this question is similar to what you asked. You can refer to it.

[When Resources of a PE file are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585817/when-resources-of-a-pe-file-are-loaded)